# Extract multiple columns from list of lists, and save in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I have the following list:

```
library(rjson)
j <- fromJSON(file='https://esgf-data.dkrz.de/esg-search/search/?offset=0&limit=1000&type=Dataset&replica=false&latest=true&project=CORDEX&domain=EUR-11&experiment=rcp85&time_frequency=day&facets=rcm_name%2Cproject%2Cproduct%2Cdomain%2Cinstitute%2Cdriving_model%2Cexperiment%2Cexperiment_family%2Censemble%2Crcm_version%2Ctime_frequency%2Cvariable%2Cvariable_long_name%2Ccf_standard_name%2Cdata_node&format=application%2Fsolr%2Bjson')
```

I am interested in extracting data from this component: `j$response$docs`, which is a list of lists. The 'internal'  lists are all supposed to have the same names.

I want to save the output to a `data.frame()` or `tibble()`.

This below works and gives the desired output, for the few selected variables:

```
nmod <- length(j$response$docs)
for (i in 1:nmod) {
    #select one list at a time
    j1 <- j$response$docs[[i]]
    tmp <- data.frame(variable=j1$variable,
                        variable_long_name=j1$variable_long_name,
                        rcm_name=j1$rcm_name,
                        driving_model=j1$driving_model,
                        cf_standard_name=j1$cf_standard_name
                        )
    #join them
    if (i==1) {
        d <- tmp
    } else {
        d <- rbind(d, tmp)
    }
}
```

However, I'd like to know if there is a more elegant and efficient way, maybe using `tidyr`, `dplyr` or `purrr`, which also would allow me to select all ¨columns¨, instead of just the few selected there.

Comment: binding the list together can be tidied up by using `bind_rows` from `dplyr` which expects a list. It could be moved outside the loop and you wouldnt need the if statement.

Comment: You can probably use something like `lapply(,'[[') ` to extract the list in the first place

Comment: @Lespied however, I do not think that works with multiple internal lists, right? I mean, I can extract one at a time with `lapply(j$response$docs, '[[', 'variable_long_name')`, but not more then one at a time. Am I missing a simple way to do it?

Comment: Problem is: list's elements have different number of elements (41 up to the 55th, 42 after, then 43, then back to 41, etc). Additionally, what you want to do with nested elements such as 'access' or 'experiment_family'?

Comment: @GGamba see the accepted answer, that is exactly what I was looking for. Missing elements should be present, and set as NA, also for all those cases where they are not in the list.

Comment: Yea I saw it, the upvote is mine, great solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with help from package *purrr*.  I thought `at_depth` might work here, but instead I ended up using nested `map_df`.

```
library(purrr)
```

Your variables are different lengths, so the first thing to do is to make sure each variable is length 1.  This can be done by collapsing each element of the inner list with `paste`.  I used commas a separator.  Doing this via `map_df` returns a 1 row `tibble`.

Here's an example with the first inner list.

```
map_df(j$response$docs[[1]], paste, collapse = ",")
```

Now we can loop through the outer lists, making a 1 row `tibble` for each.  We use `map_df` to bind each of these together.  The output is a 832 row `tibble`, one row per list.  I used the `.id` argument to add a grouping variable to the result, which may not be needed.

```
d1 = map_df(j$response$docs, ~map_df(.x, paste, collapse = ","))
d1

# A tibble: 832 × 45
   group                                                                                                   id  version
   <chr>                                                                                                <chr>    <chr>
1      1   cordex.output.EUR-11.DMI.ICHEC-EC-EARTH.rcp85.r3i1p1.HIRHAM5.v1.day.clh.v20131119|cordexesg.dmi.dk 20131119
2      2 cordex.output.EUR-11.DMI.ICHEC-EC-EARTH.rcp85.r3i1p1.HIRHAM5.v1.day.clivi.v20131119|cordexesg.dmi.dk 20131119
3      3  cordex.output.EUR-11.DMI.ICHEC-EC-EARTH.rcp85.r3i1p1.HIRHAM5.v1.day.rsds.v20131119|cordexesg.dmi.dk 20131119
4      4  cordex.output.EUR-11.DMI.ICHEC-EC-EARTH.rcp85.r3i1p1.HIRHAM5.v1.day.rlds.v20131119|cordexesg.dmi.dk 20131119
5      5  cordex.output.EUR-11.DMI.ICHEC-EC-EARTH.rcp85.r3i1p1.HIRHAM5.v1.day.rsus.v20131119|cordexesg.dmi.dk 20131119
6      6  cordex.output.EUR-11.DMI.ICHEC-EC-EARTH.rcp85.r3i1p1.HIRHAM5.v1.day.rlus.v20131119|cordexesg.dmi.dk 20131119
7      7  cordex.output.EUR-11.DMI.ICHEC-EC-EARTH.rcp85.r3i1p1.HIRHAM5.v1.day.rsdt.v20131119|cordexesg.dmi.dk 20131119
8      8  cordex.output.EUR-11.DMI.ICHEC-EC-EARTH.rcp85.r3i1p1.HIRHAM5.v1.day.rsut.v20131119|cordexesg.dmi.dk 20131119
9      9  cordex.output.EUR-11.DMI.ICHEC-EC-EARTH.rcp85.r3i1p1.HIRHAM5.v1.day.rlut.v20131119|cordexesg.dmi.dk 20131119
10    10   cordex.output.EUR-11.DMI.ICHEC-EC-EARTH.rcp85.r3i1p1.HIRHAM5.v1.day.psl.v20131119|cordexesg.dmi.dk 20131119
# ... with 822 more rows, and 42 more variables:
```

If you want to get multiple rows for the variables that were greater than length 1, such as `access` and `experiment_family`, you can use `tidyr::separate_rows` to separate the data onto multiple rows.

```
tidyr::separate_rows(d1, experiment_family)
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was looking for. `purrr` and `dplyr` are so brilliant once you get the hang of them.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `rjson` go with this:

```
library(jsonlite)
j <- jsonlite::fromJSON('https://esgf-data.dkrz.de/esg-search/search/?offset=0&limit=1000&type=Dataset&replica=false&latest=true&project=CORDEX&domain=EUR-11&experiment=rcp85&time_frequency=day&facets=rcm_name%2Cproject%2Cproduct%2Cdomain%2Cinstitute%2Cdriving_model%2Cexperiment%2Cexperiment_family%2Censemble%2Crcm_version%2Ctime_frequency%2Cvariable%2Cvariable_long_name%2Ccf_standard_name%2Cdata_node&format=application%2Fsolr%2Bjson')

# The names you wan to find in the nested returned data
look_for <- c('variable','variable_long_name' ,
              'rcm_name','driving_model',
              'cf_standard_name')


new_df <- as.data.frame(sapply(look_for, function(i){
  unlist(j$response$docs[[i]])
}))

str(new_df)
'data.frame':   832 obs. of  5 variables:
$ variable          : chr  "clh" "clivi" "rsds" "rlds" ...
$ variable_long_name: chr  "High Level Cloud Fraction" "Ice Water Path" "Surface Downwelling Shortwave Radiation" "Surface Downwelling Longwave Radiation" ...
$ rcm_name          : chr  "HIRHAM5" "HIRHAM5" "HIRHAM5" "HIRHAM5" ...
$ driving_model     : chr  "ICHEC-EC-EARTH" "ICHEC-EC-EARTH" "ICHEC-EC-EARTH" "ICHEC-EC-EARTH" ...
$ cf_standard_name  : chr  "cloud_area_fraction_in_atmosphere_layer" "atmosphere_cloud_ice_content" "surface_downwelling_shortwave_flux_in_air" "surface_downwelling_longwave_flux_in_air" ...
```